# SAS DS2 Get HTTPS page content using certificate

Tags: https, sas, certificate

I am running a SAS DS2 program and the below code gets the page contents from the https page using username and password. The code works fine in my local env but not in the clustered server.

Proposed solution in a blog :

Include sslcalistloc config variable in sasv9_local.cfg to resolve this error. I added the below line in the server but still the same error as below.

-sslcalistloc /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.trust.crt

---

```
    h.createGetMethod(url);

    auth =  put('username:Password',$base64x64.);
    h.addRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' || auth);

    h.executeMethod();

    status = h.getStatusCode();
    put 'Requested resource for country code:' code 'executeMethod() status:'    status;

    if status eq 200 then
        do;
            /* 200 = OK */
            /* retrieve the body from the response that came from the server */
            h.getResponseBodyAsString(body, rc);
        end;

    return body;
```

ERROR: 
        OpenSSL error 336134278 (0x14090086) occurred in SSL_connect/accept at      line 5377, the error message is "error:14090086:SSL
       routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed".
        ERROR: Encryption run-time execution error

Comment: Wich version (maintenance release) of SAS are you running? Have you read the documentation regarding sslcalistloc, sslcacertdir and SDM? http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/secref/68007/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0k2dumbsgs89fn1vew0vsd9cokh.htm http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/secref/68007/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0n1y5gwevy312n13h5bm4yf6quy.htm

Comment: I will check the documentation, I am using version: 9.04.01M3P062415. DO you suggest adding CA certificate through deployment manager @Jetzler ?

Comment: Yes, I have not run into problems regarding CAs but SAS recommends using the SDM in recent versions.

Comment: @Jetzler Reworded slightly that's better as an answer, not as a comment.  You're giving the OP a suggestion to solve the problem.